# How does vertex array work with materials?

Tags: opengl

My model structure contains a VertexList, ColorList and a NormalList. I'm going to do the TextureCoordList, but I'm a little confused with this. Some polygon has texture, some doesn't, and some has another texture as the other. So how does it work? I render the model as one Vertex buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Texture coordinates don't have any information on what texture, if any, they are being used for. They're just numbers that specify where on the texture OpenGL should sample. You can render the same mesh with the same texture coordinates with different textures, or even no textures at all.

If you're using shaders, you don't even have to use the texture coordinates for texturing; you can use them for whatever you want (though in that case, consider renaming them by using vertex attributes instead).